# 2D Arrays Minesweeper Random Mine Objects & Surrounding Mines

Tags: java, arrays

Another couple of questions for an array of arrays minesweeper game

1.) My code (with Merlin's tutoring) is outputting a correct number of mines. Sometimes. How can I fix this? **ANSWERED**

Example:

```
Enter width of board: 5
Enter height of board: 5
Enter number of mines: 5
   0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  .  .  . 
2| .  .  .  .  * 
3| .  .  *  .  . 
4| *  .  .  *  * 

Enter width of board: 5
Enter height of board: 5
Enter number of mines: 5
   0  1  2  3  4
0| *  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  *  .  . 
2| .  .  .  .  . 
3| .  *  .  .  . 
4| *  .  .  .  *
```

MineField Code:

```
public MineField(int w, int h, int m)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    mineField = new State[w][h];
    surroundingMines = new int[w][h];
    initialiseMineField = new int[w][h];
    traceOn = true; //set to false before submitting
    width = w;
    height = h;
    mineCount = m;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            mineField[i][j] = State.COVERED;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int a = r.nextInt(w);
            int b = r.nextInt(h);
            if (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        mineField[r.nextInt(w)][r.nextInt(h)] = State.MINED;
    }
}
```

State enums:

```
public enum State {
    /** Cell is mined */
    MINED,
    /** Player uncovered (hit) mine */
    EXPLODED,
    /** Cell is not mined but unexplored */
    COVERED,
    /** Cell is not mined and has been explored */
    CLEARED,
    /** Cell has been flagged and contains a mine */
    FLAGGED,
    /** Cell has been flagged but does not contain a mine */
    MISFLAGGED;
```

Required state chars:

```
public char toChar(int surroundingMines, boolean showTruth) {
    switch (this) {
        case EXPLODED: return '+';
        case COVERED: return '.';
        case CLEARED: return surroundingMines == 0 ? ' ' : String.valueOf(surroundingMines).charAt(0);
        case FLAGGED: return 'F';
        case MINED: return showTruth ? '*' : '.';
        default /* MISFLAGGED */: return showTruth ? 'x' : 'F';
    }
}
```

2.) How am I able to display the mines that surrounds a cell within my array output of say:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  .  .  . 
2| .  .  .  .  * 
3| .  .  *  .  . 
4| *  .  .  *  *
```

with:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  .  1  1 
2| .  .  1  2  * 
3| 1  2  *  2  2 
4| *  1  2  *  *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops

```
for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int a = r.nextInt(w);
        int b = r.nextInt(h);
        if (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED)
        {
            mineField[a][b] = State.MINED;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah god, I had that before, but I had accidentally entered it twice and assumed it was broken. Thank you!